# NHibernate. get singleOrDefault

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following method. This returns a single unqiue order. However i just want the first result. What is the best way to achieve this. Of course i could return a List and then get the first result from that.

ie `.List<Order>().SingleOrDefault();`

Surely there is away through the criteria api to acheive this?

```
    Model.Order order = _session
            .CreateCriteria(typeof(Model.Order))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("UserName", user.UserName))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CompanyId", companyId))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("OrderStatus", OrderStatusHelper.OrderOpen()))
            .AddOrder(sortOrder)
            .UniqueResult<Model.Order>(); // results not always unique
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's slightly less complicated than Saint Gerbil proposed:

```
Model.Order order = _session
        .CreateCriteria<Model.Order>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("UserName", user.UserName))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CompanyId", companyId))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("OrderStatus", OrderStatusHelper.OrderOpen()))
        .AddOrder(sortOrder)
        .SetMaxResults(1)
        .UniqueResult<Model.Order>();
```

This will do a query using the DB syntax for retrieving only one record.

If there are no records matching the criteria, `UniqueResult` returns null.

You could also use NHibernate Linq (either the 2.x contrib provider, or the one integrated in NH 3.x). In that case, you should use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `SingleOrDefault` to achieve the result you want.

Comment: Note that FirstOrDefault is not the same as SingleOrDefault. Single should throw an exception when more than 1 record is found where as First will just return the first record found.

Answer (score 1):

```
    IList<Model.Order> order = _session
        .CreateCriteria(typeof(Model.Order))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("UserName", user.UserName))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CompanyId", companyId))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("OrderStatus", OrderStatusHelper.OrderOpen()))
        .AddOrder(sortOrder)
        .SetMaxResults(1)
        .List<Model.Order>(); // results not always unique

        if(order.Count == 1)
        {
             return order[0];
        }
        else
        {
             return default(Model.Order)
        }
```

Something like this.